# Split image on printable sheet

Tags: ubuntu, images, imagemagick

I have a logo in png on which I specified the size in centimeter ( 40x45 cm).
I need to split that images  on two A4 sheet to be able to print it.

I tried to use convert but I have to specified the size in pixel:

```
convert logo.png -crop 1152x1584 +repage page%03d.png
```

Which tool can use a png as input and generate a list of image in pdf to print it on A4 sheets?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify in other units than pixels, use the following parameters:

[**-units**](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#units)

> The units of image resolution.
>
> Choose from: Undefined, PixelsPerInch, or PixelsPerCentimeter. This
> option is normally used in conjunction with the -density option.

[**-density**](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#density) width / *width*X*height*

> Set the horizontal and vertical resolution of an image for rendering to devices.